# ¿Es posible declarar una variable que contenga un if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

¿Es posible declarar una variable que contenga un if statement?
El siguiente pseudocódigo (escrito solo con la idea de ilustrar el ejemplo), representa la idea que se persigue, esto es, que la variable m tome un valor diferente dependiendo del valor de j.

```
j = [1, 2, 3]
m =  if j[0]:
            [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.0, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]
     if j[1]:
            [{'b': 0.5, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]
     if j[2]:
            [{'b': 1.0, 'x': 1.0, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: No recuerdo nunca ver algo parecido. De cualquier manera podrias igualmente tener 3 if normales y asignar el valor a la variable segun sea el caso, que daria lo mismo si es que se pudiera hacer los if dentro de la asignación, de todos modos se tendrian que evaluar las condiciones.

Comment: Debería ser `j[2]` en vez de `j[3]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es una asignación rápida de una variable según una determinada condición. Hay algunas formas de hacerlo (modifiqué un poco los valores de tu ejemplo por que estabas retornando siempre la misma lista):

#### Mediante una función

```
def valor(j):

  if j == 1:
    return [{'b': 0.8, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]
  elif j == 2:
    return [{'b': 1.8, 'x': 1.5, 'm': 1.02} for _ in range(100)]
  elif j == 3:
    return [{'b': 2.8, 'x': 2.5, 'm': 2.02} for _ in range(100)]
  else:
    return None

j = 2
m = valor(j)
print(m)
```

Es una buena alternativa ya que permite verificar mejor la condición `j`, por ejemplo devolver un valor default si no se eligió ningún valor esperado.

#### Mediante el uso de diccionarios

```
opciones = {1:[{'b': 0.8, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)],
            2:[{'b': 1.8, 'x': 1.5, 'm': 1.02} for _ in range(100)],
            3:[{'b': 2.8, 'x': 2.5, 'm': 2.02} for _ in range(100)]}


j = 2
m = opciones[j]
print(m)
```

Es una asignación directa desde un diccionario que tiene como clave las opciones válidas, se emitirá un `KeyError` si usas cualquier valor de `j` no contemplado, salvo que accedas al diccionario usando el método `get()`:

```
m = opciones.get(j, None)
```

Answer (score 5):

Literalmente como lo estas preguntando no es posible. Aun asi, existe un par de formas de hacer algo muy parecido en Python. La primera es con los llamados Operadores de Coalescencia, y se usan de la siguiente forma:

```
m = j[0] or [{'b': 0.8, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]
```

Esto se evalua de la siguiente manera. Si el primer termino/variable es verdadero, entonces a la variable se le asigna ese primer termino/variable. Si el primer termino/variable es falso, entonces a la variable se le asigna el segundo termino/variable. Ten en cuenta que solo se evalua el primer termino/variable.

La segunda es con el operador ternario, que es bastante parecido. Tendrias que usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
m = [{'b': 0.8, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)] if j[0] else None
```

De esta forma, el valor por defecto es la lista que estas indicando cuando la condición se cumple y cuando no se cumple la condición, entonces la variable toma el valor `None`.

Como te decia, no es exactamente hacer un if dentro de la asignación, si no más bien evaular para asignar. Esto es una forma poco usual de hacerlo, pero es lo más parecido a tu pregunta. Supongo que podrias anidar de alguna forma las operaciones en alguna de estas dos formas. Ya que probablemente estes investigando los medios para llegar a un objetivo final, te recomiendo **mejor hacerlo por funciones** como lo indica la **respuesta de Patricio.**

Puedes ver más información de estos operadores en la [documentación oficial de tu versión de Python.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) y tambien en esta [pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105500/compressing-x-if-x-else-y-statement-in-python).